# WPF - Strange behaviour of TextBox when disabling from view model

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this xaml code in user control:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsEnabled="{Binding CanEditOpenCut}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding OpenCut}" Margin="5" Width="80"/>
        <TextBlock Text="°C" />
 </StackPanel>
```

And I have viewmodel with properties:

```
    private decimal _openCut;
    public decimal OpenCut
    {
        get
        {
            return _openCut;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Set(ref _openCut, value))
            {
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => OpenCut);

                if (this.PrevRunConfig != null)
                {
                    this.PrevRunConfig.CloseCut = _openCut;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private bool _canEditOpenCut;
    public bool CanEditOpenCut
    {
        get
        {
            return _canEditOpenCut;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Set(ref _canEditOpenCut, value))
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the binding works fine when I set in textbox e.g. 40 then I have it in my OpenCut property in viewmodel. If I set something in viewmodel I get it in the textbox. So far its working. Now I try to disable the textbox and reset the value to some default like 20. There are 2 scenarios one is working and one not.

1) If I set e.g. 40 in textbox, then lose focus and then set CanEditOpenCut = false and OpenCut = 20, everything works I see 20 in textbox.

2) I set 40 to the textbox, I DO NOT !!! lose focus of the textbox, then I set CanEditOpenCut = false and OpenCut = 20. Now it is not working I still see 40 in textbox although the values in viewmodel are correct.

Thanks for any help,

Tomas

Comment: try to change `{Binding OpenCut}` to `{Binding OpenCut, Mode=TwoWay}`

Comment: In second scenario you are running into deferred nature of wpf, it *likes* to queue things via dispatcher. When you set `CanEditOpenCut` this should lead to everything disabled, but it's not happening immediately. Therefore your `OpenCut = 20` is called before `TextBox` is actually disabled, focus removal happens later and as a result - binding will update source with entered value (on focus lost, which is default mode) and this is why you see `40`. I can't explain *"the values in viewmodel are correct"*, hopefully you will find it out yourself.

Comment: Try to queue your change: `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => OpenCut = 20)` (maybe using `InvokeAsync`) after you reset `CanEditOpenCut`.

Comment: Thank you Sinatr. The values in viewmodel are changed in setter so when i put breakpoint in code I see that 40 is changed to 20. But in the control remains 40. Yes, I do not change these values like I wrote, it is a bit complicated it involves messaging and there is DispatcherHelper.RunAsync(() =>...) and there is the change. I thought it has something with control and binding.